# apply code changes NetBeans

Tags: java-8, netbeans-8.2

llevo ya varios días intentando hacer esto y no lo consigo. He de dcir, que al hacer debug sobre mi proyecto, si que me para en los puntos de interrupción, pero, en la versión que tenía antes (7.4) podía modificar código, y aplicar los cambios. Ahora, me he cambiado de ordenador, y tengo la versión 8.2, y no consigo hacer esto último, ni poniendo en la opción de debug Apply code changes after save (in "Compile on Save" mode only) ni con el botoncito para ello, que es como lo hacía antes. 
Primero: Donde configuro en el 8.2 lo de "Compile on Save" mode only, no lo encuentro por ningún lado... 
Segundo: Alguien ha tenido este problema, y lo consiguió solucionar?

Un saludo y muchas gracias!
Marta

Comment: Click derecho en tu proyecto>Properties>Build>Compiling y ahi estará el compile on save que buscas

Comment: Pueees, en el NetBeans 8.2, no está... o por lo menos, no está tal cual lo comentas... En properties tengo:
-General
-Java Sourdes
-Java Sources Classpath
-Output
-Build and Run
-Formating

Y no encuentro en ninguna de estas el Compile on save... Lo que me extraña de todo es que el debug si que me funciona, y me para en los puntos y veo que hay en cada variable, pero esto, no lo consigo hacer funcionar.... Loca me estoy volviendo!!! XD

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes seleccionar tu proyecto y darle click derecho apra abrir le menú contextual, luego seleccionas `Properties`

[image: menú contextual]

De allí en el dialogo que se abra vas a `Build>Compiling`

Así se ve en proyectos ANT que son los más comunes
[image: opción compile on save en proyecto ant de netbeans]

en proyectos maven se ve así

[image: opción compile on save en proyecto maven de netbeans]